# Importing (libGDX) Gradle project crashes Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, crash, gradle

I am trying to Import a gradle project created by the libGDX Project Generator into Eclipse.

I am using `Eclipse Kepler v4.3.2` with;

- `ADT 23.0.2`
- `Gradle` installed from `http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle`

I create libGDX project and try to import it to Eclipse following this procedure:

```
File->Import->Gradle->Gradle Project->Choose Project Folder->Build Model->Tick->Finish
```

After the progress bar reaches 35%-50%, Eclipse stops responding so I close it. Why does Eclipse stop responding and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It seems like I had to install a clean and fully updated version of Eclipse from `https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/`

I guess my Eclipse was;

1. Not updated.
2. Had a plugin/modification which effected importing a gradle project.